# Is it possible to run multiple expressions in a single function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to combine a VectorPlot and a ComplexListPlot into one function, so that I can manipulate the same variables for both simultaneously.

The code I have looks like this

```
phasePlane = 
 VectorPlot[{(a*x) + (b*y), (c*x) + (d*y)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, VectorPoints -> {"Regular", 10}, 
  StreamPoints -> {{0, 0}}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> Red, StreamScale -> None]

zPlot = ComplexListPlot[Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], Frame -> False,
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}]

combinedPlot[] := 
 Manipulate[(phasePlane; 
   zPlot), {a, {-1, 0, 1}}, {b, {-1, 0, 1}}, {c, {-1, 0, 1}}, {d, {-1,
     0, 1}}]
```

When I actually run `combinedPlot[]`, it only gives me the ComplexListPlot, and none of the points are actually evaluated on the graph. [combinedPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kX85.png)

Is there anything I can actually do to combine them, or is it impossible?

Comment: For the record, there is also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try `Manipulate[{phasePlane,zPlot},...]` which should make two plots, either side by side or one above the other depending on size. The enclosing `{}` should make Mathematica think it needs to create a vector or list of two items and the items just happen to be plots. There are other things you can do if you can't stand the sight of the `{}` around your two plots, but see if you can display the plots first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are saying you want to have two separate plots and `Manipulate` for different parameters `{a,b,c,d}`. I define the plotting functions outside of `Manipulate` first (this is not necessary, I just liked doing it this way better):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, phasePlane, zPlot];

phasePlane[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 VectorPlot[{(a*x) + (b*y), (c*x) + (d*y)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, VectorPoints -> {"Regular", 10}, 
  StreamPoints -> {{0, 0}}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> Red, StreamScale -> None]

zPlot[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 ComplexListPlot[Eigenvalues[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green]
```

And now I make a list of `{phasePlane,zPlot}` and display it as `TableForm`:

```
Manipulate[{phasePlane[a, b, c, d], zPlot[a, b, c, d]} // TableForm
 , {a, {-1, 0, 1}}, {b, {-1, 0, 1}}, {c, {-1, 0, 1}}, {d, {-1, 0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also come check out the [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)